# PHP, sort an array depending its entries (xNUMBERxNUMBERxNUMBER)

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting

In PHP, below a example of an array :

```
$version = [
    "x3x3x2",
    "x10x11x0",
    "x180x7x1",
    "x10x1x7",
    "x2x0x4",
    "x3x3x1",
]
```

Each entries follow this pattern 'xNxNxN' (a char 'x' and a number N, three times)

I want sort each entries of this array by numbers, left to right. The result as expected is :

```
$version = [
    "x2x0x4",
    "x3x3x1",
    "x3x3x2",
    "x10x1x0",
    "x10x11x7",
    "x180x7x1",
]
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: why do you have this data? Because it looks super artificial, so if this is just a homework exercise, there is an answer, and that answer is not the right answer for "real" code.

Comment: The [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function was created for use cases like this one.

Comment: Did you try any of the standard PHP sort functions and find they were not doing what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [built-in function to compare version numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php). Just combine it with `usort`.

```
usort($version, 'version_compare');
```

Result:

```
var_dump($version);
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "x2x0x4"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "x3x3x1"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "x3x3x2"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "x10x1x7"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "x10x11x0"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "x180x7x1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution by keeping only numbers and sorting it using `usort`

```
usort($version,function($a,$b){
    $astr = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $a);
    $bstr = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $b);
    return $astr - $bstr;
});
print_r($version);
```

[usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8c6f9785119fd2ac96931e00b96b53e90816d95).

Comment: This would sort `x1x10x10` after `x2x1x1`. I'm assuming this is undesirable since it's implied the strings are version numbers.

Comment: @MattRaines I tested you can check [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4319c4dfc3026927da94f0fd3e211a5eb07d1581). It working fine.